# Eventbrite API event_search orderby and pagination

Tags: node.js, api, pagination, eventbrite

I am playing around with the event_search API from Eventbrite using the NPM package.

Unfortunately I don't quite understand how the paging works. did not find anything on the official doc or forums.

If I make a call like this

```
var params = {'keywords':query,'paging':2,'max':100}
eventbrite.event_search(params,function(err,data){
    console.log(data);
);
```

I will receive as a result:

```
{ result:
    { events:
    [ [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object],
    [Object] ] 
    },
error: null
}
{ summary:
    { total_items: 170,
    first_event: 6756066577,
    last_event: 9079524101,
    filters: { keywords: 'hackathon','page':10 },
    num_showing: 10 }
}
```

I don't really see the logic of the way events are ordered, it's not by id, neither by starting date.
I from that perspective I don't see how I could go through the rest of the results.

If you faced the same problem or if you have any hint.
Thank you for your help ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question -- I'm a Product Manager on the Eventbrite API, so I'd love to help you out.

On the /event_search API method, there is an argument that you can set for how you sort the results -- you can set "sort_by" to a couple different values (Date, ID, name, and city). I would recommend sorting by ID, because it's the most consistent.

Once you do an initial pull from our directory, you can pull a subset of the total events by filtering on the 'date_created' or 'date_modified' arguments... so that you're only receiving events that have recently been added or updated.

Here is the documentation for the current /event_search API: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Mitch for your answer.
To complete your answer, what I understood later in the day :
When you do a event_search call there is a `summary` hash that contains info about the subset.
Also the `page` params gives you access to the n subset of the result set.

One way to get all the set corresponding to your request :
1. First call with count_only parameter
2. Determine number of pages
3. Get each page individually

Could you confirm ? thanks